# Problem uploading photos when I show page as subdomain

Tags: plugins, customization, pages, uploads, subdomains

I created a subdomain and created an index.php file in it. Then I gave the identity of the Dokan dashboard page to the index.php I created. So I made the dashboard page as subdomain and everything works fine. But there is a problem, it is not possible to add a product photo. While uploading the photo it gives the following problem:

“The server cannot process the image. This can happen if the server is busy or does not have enough resources to complete the task. Uploading a smaller image might help. the recommended maximum size is 2560 pixels”.

To solve this I increased the size but it still didn't work, it gave the same problem. I copied the wp-content file to the subdomain folder and it still didn't work. I would appreciate your help, thank you…